# Button text pushes away the padding in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, button, padding

Markup:

```html
<input type="button" value="random text random text random text random text random text"
       style="padding-left:20px; text-align:left; width:100px;" />
```

Here `padding-left` works fine until I set the width, chopping the text off in the middle, which pushes `padding-left` away. This is a Firefox problem only btw. Works fine in all other browsers. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/aB25a/1

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll do that right away.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/aB25a/1/

Comment: So the point is that Firefox tries to center the the text in the button, including allowing it to overflow into the left padding.  It turns out that some sites rely on this behavior; that's why it was implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the info Boris. Do you know of any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Use a `<button>` with a `<span>` inside containing the text and set the padding on the `<span>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `<button>` element, this gives you more control over what happens with its contents:

```html
<button class="wrong">
  <span>this pushes text to the left, ignoring padding</span>
</button>
```

And the styles then are:

```css
.wrong {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrong span {
    margin-left:30px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Example that should work in all browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/p8mg8/1/

Answer (score 0):

try using `margin-left` instead of your `padding-left`, also I recommend to use classes and CSS files.

Set `width:auto;`, or at some value.

Comment: Here is an answer I previously wrote which should aid Sebs answer regarding margin over padding - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10701790/1160747

Comment: That's where it goes wrong. =) Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/aB25a/1/

Comment: `width:auto;` instead of `width:100px` :)

Comment: but what if I need the button to be 100px?

Comment: than it cannot have this much text :) Also you can surround it with another Div with `width:100px;` so it will be cut off anyway.

Comment: Yupp, they're pretty small buttons :) I apologize if I'm missing something, but that results in this http://jsfiddle.net/aB25a/2/

Comment: because you have too much text.

Comment: Ok, but the text in my buttons are long and needs to be hidden like I've shown. It works exactly like I want it to in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to make it work:

```
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner { margin-left:20px };
```